# System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MyApp.Core.App' threw an exception

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, typeinitializeexception

I am writing a Xamarin.Forms application. It was working just before, but now it is throwing an exception on this line of my Android project:

```
global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
LoadApplication(new App());
```

It throws the exception:

> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'MyApp.Core.App' threw an exception.

The constructor doesn't even get called. I don't even know what I did to cause this...does anyone have any idea?

Here is my code for App.xaml.cs

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public static INavigation Navigation
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public static Lazy<LoungeListPage> LoungeListView { get; set; } = new Lazy<LoungeListPage>();
    public static Lazy<LoungePage> LoungeView { get; set; } = new Lazy<LoungePage>();
    public static Lazy<EditFencePage> FenceView { get; set; } = new Lazy<EditFencePage>();
    public static Lazy<NewFencePage> NewFenceView { get; set; } = new Lazy<NewFencePage>();
    public static ILoungeService LoungeService { get; set; } = new LoungeService();
    public static ILoginService LoginService { get; set; } = new LoginService();

    public App ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DependencyService.Register<PlatformDependentCode>();
        DependencyService.Get<IPlatformDependentCode>().OnFirstPageLoaded = this.OnFirstPageLoaded;

        var rootPage = new NavigationPage(new MyApp.Core.MainPage());
        MainPage = rootPage;
        App.Navigation = rootPage.Navigation;
    }

    protected override void OnStart ()
    {
        // Handle when your app starts

        Plugin.Geolocator.CrossGeolocator.Current.DesiredAccuracy = 0.001;
    }

    protected override void OnSleep ()
    {
        // Handle when your app sleeps
    }

    protected override void OnResume ()
    {
        // Handle when your app resumes
    }

    private void OnFirstPageLoaded()
    {
        var deviceInfo = DependencyService.Get<IPlatformDependentCode>().GeneralPlatformDependent.GetDeviceInfo();
        LoginService.InitializeDevice(deviceInfo);
    }
}
```

And in App.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="MyApp.Core.App">
    <Application.Resources>

    <!-- Application resource dictionary -->

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please see the documentation of `TypeInitializationException` (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.typeinitializationexception(v=vs.110).aspx))

> The exception that is thrown as a wrapper around the exception thrown by the class initializer.

It seems as if there was an exception thrown by your type initializer code. Since there is no static constructor and I would not suspect `new Lazy<T>()` to throw an exception, I'd guess that the issue is in

```
public static ILoungeService LoungeService { get; set; } = new LoungeService();
public static ILoginService LoginService { get; set; } = new LoginService();
```

Supposedly one of those throws an exception. You could check by creating the instances from your constructor and log that exception (temporarily).

```
public static ILoungeService LoungeService { get; set; }
public static ILoginService LoginService { get; set; } 

public App ()
{
    try
    {
        LoungeService = new LoungeService();
        LoginService = new LoginService();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(e);
        throw;
    }

    InitializeComponent();

    // ...
}
```

(or register them with your `DependencyService` right away).